# Removing disconnected cells in a stream network raster using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polyline-creation, hydrography

I've got a predicted stream network raster with cells values 0 (not a stream) and 1 (is a stream). My end goal is to create a network of connected polylines, but unfortunately there are some areas that are disconnected that we want to include in the final file, and some we do not - we have decided to get rid of any segments disconnected from the larger network by more than 2 cells.

Therefore, I would only like to keep the cells with value 1 that are either 1. connected to the larger network or 2. within 2 cells (~40ft) of this main network. The areas circled in green below are what we're hoping to maintain, while removing the areas circled in red.

[image: initial stream line raster showing orphans and disconnected "true" streams]

I have tried using Spatial Analyst --> Region Group then reclassification (using a cutoff of count = 7) to remove the "orhpans" as we call we them, but that also gets rid of some areas that shouldn’t be cut, like a segment that’s short but only disconnected by 1 or 2 cells. See image below - areas in red should be maintained but are not.

[image: product of Region Group reclassification]

I understand why using the cutoff of 7 wouldn't necessarily work, as it would cut out small segments that are disconnected by 1 or 2 cells. I'm not sure what approach I SHOULD use, however.

Comment: I think your question will attract quicker and easier to apply answers (and more votes) if you edit one or other of your two parts out into a separate question. We mention the desirability of one question per question in the [Tour].

Comment: I've answered part 1. please split your question so that it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a remark, topological problem are better solved with vector, but in this case there is a raster-based solution. For instance you convert to lines 'raster to lines), then you use "[extend line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extend_Line/001v00000004000000/)" with a tolerance

use "expand" of one pixel to create a buffer around all your lines. Then you can do your region group and remove small parts (e.g. reclassify with threshold = 20, remember you have "buffers") for isolated groups. Finally, assuming that rivers are 1 and background is zero, you multiply the original with the cleaned buffer (or use a conditional). Alternatively, you can use "Thin" as a last step, which might slightly modify your lines but keeps the connectivity of nearby segments.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may not completely understand what you're suggesting, as multiplying the original will give me zeroes where they shouldn't be again. (Something that became a "1" in the new file would become "0" again when multiplied by the old.) This method does connect everything I need connected, but unfortunately both thin and shrink were ineffective.

I am open to a vector-based solution if necessary. Can you recommend an approach? The lines produced by converting the initial raster are not ideal, so I thought about manipulating a point file based on the raster.

Comment: I am focusing on your first figure: removing red and keeping green). the expand will be larger than the original. expanding by one will "connect" pixels with a gap smaller than 3 pixels. You then remove all the group of pixels that are too small, then you clean up.

Comment: I see the issue now. I not only need to keep the areas in green, I need to connect them to form a continuous network. I did not make that clear. I feel like I should ask about connecting those segments as a separate question.